# accessing textview within a fragment in activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, communication

I wanted to use Fragments with in the ActionBar. Unfortunately it looks like its really complicated. My Fragments have Textviews and I want to be able to communicate with them out of my activity. Before I started to use Fragments I could access them with

```
private EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextName);
```

So I was able to receive the editText value when a user clicked on save. How should I do this the Fragment-way?

Activity:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_recipe);
    getSupportActionBar().setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(0, com.actionbarsherlock.app.ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_HOME | com.actionbarsherlock.app.ActionBar.DISPLAY_USE_LOGO | com.actionbarsherlock.app.ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_TITLE);

    ActionBar.Tab newTab0 = getSupportActionBar()
            .newTab()
            .setText(R.string.fragment_general)
            .setTabListener(
            new MyTabListener<GeneralFragment>(this, "general",
                            GeneralFragment.class));


    getSupportActionBar().addTab(newTab0);

}
public static class MyTabListener<T extends Fragment> implements
        TabListener {
    private Fragment mFragment;
    private final Activity mActivity;
    private final String mTag;
    private final Class<T> mClass;

    /**
     * * Constructor used each time a new tab is created. * * @param
     * activity * The host Activity, used to instantiate the fragment * @param
     * tag * The identifier tag for the fragment * @param clz * The
     * fragment's Class, used to instantiate the fragment
     */

    public MyTabListener(Activity activity, String tag, Class<T> clz) {
        mActivity = activity;
        mTag = tag;
        mClass = clz;
    }

    /* The following are each of the ActionBar.TabListener callbacks */

    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // Check if the fragment is already initialized
        if (mFragment == null) {
            // If not, instantiate and add it to the activity
            mFragment = Fragment.instantiate(mActivity, mClass.getName());
            ft.add(android.R.id.content, mFragment, mTag);
        } else {
            // If it exists, simply attach it in order to show it
            //ft.setCustomAnimations(android.R.animator.fade_in, R.animator.animationtest);
            ft.attach(mFragment);
        }
    }

    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        if (mFragment != null) {
            //ft.setCustomAnimations(android.R.animator.fade_in, R.animator.test);
            ft.detach(mFragment);
        }
    }

    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should call getView() on the Fragment and then use findViewById() on the view returned.

Of course, it won't return anything until after the view has been created, so you may have to call it somewhere besides onCreate.

Comment: Isn't the view being created when I add the fragment as a Tab?

Comment: not necessarily. you should set some breakpoints and test. the view is created in onCreateView which isn't the same as onCreate.

Comment: toadzky has  a point. You would be able to call getView() for much easier access. But yes, the View is being created, unfortunately not every method has scope to access it directly like you are assuming it should be.

Comment: Fragment general = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_general);
  View generalView = general.getView();
  generalView.findViewById(R.id.editTextName); I will try this in my Save method

Comment: It can't find a Fragment :-/ works with: Fragment general = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("general");

Comment: you probably aren't setting an id on the fragment. i'm don't think you can set the id from anywhere but xml.

Comment: If you are using a ListFragment to which you added additional items, you might need to call LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) getView().getParent(); TextView textView = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.textView);

Answer (score 1):

Well, you need to inflate an xml file, or create one from scratch, though I wouldn't recommend it, unless you like the extra work :) But with an Activity, the `setContentView()` inflates your xml file, and subsequently in `onCreate()` you can access it the way you are use to. Mind you, if you try accessing a layout View outside of onCreate without the parent View, you will be getting the same issue. Unless you made a global variable. Since onCreate is where a developer will usually always start things off, Android made it easy to just omit the parent View from the `findViewById`.

Assuming you have an xml file called edit.xml:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
//this method is found within your Fragment, which you must ovverride
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.edit, container, false);
private EditText editText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editTextName);
//...
}
```

Feel free to check out the Android docs on Fragments to get a better understanding of why I chose to do it in that method instead of the Fragments `onCreate`, etc.

Comment: Thanks. I'm using a xml for styling the Fragments. In your example, how is the variable "editText" usable in my Activity?

Comment: From what I can tell, you don't give it direct access to use it in your Activity. But it doesn't matter. When the Fragment takes the screen, it will have access to it. Whatever you wish to do you must do from the Fragment. So in your case I guess, you want to send it to the Activity. So send the Fragment a listener upon creation, and when editText gets some info, then have it sent to your Activity.

Comment: well but this is ugly. I want to get the TextEdit values when the user click to save from fragmentA and other values from fragmentB to store them in a object in the Activity and store this object in my sqllite database. Now I should write a listener for each textView ? This fragment-way inflates a little easy thing to a big balloon...

Comment: I completely understand your frustration with this method. I will say this. I assumed you would need to do some work from within the Fragment itself. In my case, I didn't have a Fragment in xml. I've never used a Fragment through xml actually. So I would have already had a View Inflated, so it was actually pretty easy to go from there. As for it being extra work. To be very honest its literally maybe 2 extra lines of code and some curly braces and parenthesis. But thats just me.