# TextView is null in Fragment

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-fragments

I've been trying to solve this for a while now, I've looked through quite a number of questions but still nothing works.

I have a `MainActivity` with a `SlideMenu`, all items open a `Fragment`. One of these `Fragments` extends to a `ListFragment`. What I'm trying to do is once a `ListItem` is selected another `Fragment` is called and displays some data...for now just a title.

When a `ListItem` is selected, I am creating an instance of the new `Fragment`, save the data in the `Bundle` and call the new `Fragment` to be displayed.

```
@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    // do something with the data
    Article a = articleList.get(position);

    Fragment articleFragment = new ArticleFragment();

    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString("title", a.title);
    articleFragment.setArguments(args);

    FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.add(R.id.frame_container, articleFragment);
    transaction.commit();
}
```

The `onCreateView` of the new `Fragment` attempts to set the text of the `TextView` with the `Bundle's` data.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_pages, container, false);

    TextView titleTextView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.article_title);

    String title = getArguments().getString("title");
    titleTextView.setText(title);

    return rootView;
}
```

The layout xmls are these two files:

**activity_article_fragment.xml**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="info.androidhive.slidingmenu.ArticleFragment"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" />
```

**fragment_article.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="info.androidhive.slidingmenu.ArticleFragment$PlaceholderFragment" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+android:id/article_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I've tried to do as many suggested...using the `View` to get the id from the xml ([accessing textview within a fragment in activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12805203/accessing-textview-within-a-fragment-in-activity), [Android : How do I update my textView in a Fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15322237/android-how-do-i-update-my-textview-in-a-fragment)) but it's still `null`.

Whilst debugging everything is working but obviously stops when attempting to set the text of the `TextView` as it is `null`.

**UPDATE**

Just did as suggested by Karakuri...text being displayed but it looks like this:

[image: Text over the first <code>ListItem</code> - might be some layout settings?]

Comment: I see `R.layout.fragment_pages` in `onCreateView()`, but the layout you showed is `res/layout/fragment_article` ?

Comment: @karakuri thanks for that - it's working although I'm getting the text over the first `ListItem` (image in question)...I'm guessing layout settings would solve this issue? Sorry I'm a bit new to Android.

Comment: Ok solved as well, I was using `FragmentTransaction.add()` instead of `FragmentTransaction.replace()`